# Google docs style comments bound to text section

Tags: django, document, comments

I am working on a project, in which documents are edited and stored in multiple revisions. As a part of the editing process, it should be possible to write comments and tie these to specific sections in the document text.

What I imagine is something close to what Google Docs does. In Google Docs, you can highlight any text element and click "Write comment". The comment will then track the text, so it is clear what exactly has been commented on.

Now I can easily imagine making something similar to this, where - when rendering the page - the document will simply be searched and the occurrence of the commented text will be highlighted, however, there are multiple problems.

Imaging this example. My document reads:

```
foo bar is the bar of fooness
```

Now I highlight this part of the text

```
foo >>bar<< is the bar of fooness
```

and write some comment. When i render the document, the first occurence of bar will be highlighted. But what if I had commented on the second occurence of bar? That wouldn't work. What if the first occurence of bar is deleted in the next revision? Then nothing should be highlighted, even though an instance of bar exists, since the subject was removed.

So the question is: How do I store comments that refer to a specific part of a document, that will change throughout revisions? Is this a known concept that I could read about? If so, what is it called?

The specific context is  a Django app, where the document is written in the Ace editor en read as HTML. Everything happens in the browser.

Comment: Wrap the text with a tag and unique id. Then you reference always the same bar. `foo <span id='comment-1'>bar<span> is the bar of foo`. You run into trouble when a comment spans other markup...

Comment: That is an idea, though it introduces another problem. Commenting should not change the contents of the document, which it would do by inserting tags.
I guess these tags could be added and removed from the document in an intelligent way, but the documents are written in a markup and then rendered to HTML, so it would be hard to maintain these tags between revisions.